# How to enable uncurated apps in AppCenter 6.0 Odin stable

Tags: software-installation, appcenter, release-odin

In Beta 2 there was a ton of software available from AppCenter. For example Inkscape or Gimp. However in stable only those few curated apps are showing. How can I enable AppCenter to show the rest?

Comment: Try sideloading something from FlatHub, as described [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/28350/19079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.deb packages can be installed in the console with dpkg -i

Flatpaks can be downloaded from the Flathub. After installing one flatpak from there, all other available flatpaks will show up in the App Center.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I am aware of other possibilities to install software, I was just wondering if this was either a terrible political decision (which Daniel confirmed to me on reddit in the meantime) or simply a misconfiguration/bug on my side. In the end,  while I do understand the decision I feel like it is pushing back the out-of-the-box experience in eOS by far. Curated or not, Apps that could be there should be there in my opinion.