# eOS 6 - Does the new AppCenter have almost no apps or is something wrong?

Tags: appcenter, release-odin

Almost all searches return no results. e.g. searches for Firefox, Discord, Wire, Signal. Is something wrong with the servers or with my installation, or is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sideloading at least one app from [FlatHub](https://flathub.org/), then restart your PC. (Also, be sure to install all updates that show up in the AppCenter.) This will add FlatHub to the list of remotes and AppCenter should start showing all FlatHub apps too.

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you have to go to https://flathub.org/ to get those apps. Then install them with the Sideload feature of eOS. Look around for info on Flathub and Sideload. You will find that it is very easy to do. Good luck!

Comment: No problem! It is my understanding that once you install your first uncurated app from Flathub, then AppCenter will automatically populate with more uncurated apps. I am not on my eOS computer right now, so I cannot confirm, but this is what I have read.

Comment: Just checked, curated apps are also not showing up (I'd just deleted my prior comment to test, thank you again).